# How do I create git commits from another person?

Tags: git

I have a project that someone else has done work on and I would like to be able to create a patch file and then import the patch but have the commit tag with their username/email.

I have no problem creating a patch file from their source, and using `git apply /path/to/patch` to apply the changes, yet if I `git commit` it will be tagged with my name.

How do I commit with an email/username manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `git commit --author="John Doe <johndoe@example.com>"`.  This will set the authorship fields to the specified identity, but the committer fields will retain your identity.  This is probably what you want (the semantic meaning is "written by this other guy, but committed to the repository by me").

Comment: If only I tried reading for `git-commit`, I was trying to find the answer in `git-format-patch`, `git-am` and `git-apply`. Thanks for your help cdhowie :)